# What does the expression "mit x mal" mean?

Tags: translation, preposition

I am reading a book in German and have come across an expression that I can't understand (to be honest I have trouble understanding the entire sentence). The book is called "Das also ist mein Leben" and the expression goes like this:

> Es ging offenbar darum, wie er **mit fünfzehn mal** vor dem
>   Klassenfiesling eingeknickt war oder so was.

My guess is that the sentence is about a boy forced to kneel down 15 times in front of a bully. But then again why would we use 'mit' instead of leaving it out?

Comment: 'vor jemandem Einknicken' is 'to give in to somebody'

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In diesem Fall ist es nicht **15 mal**, sondern die Altersangabe **mit 15**.

Die folgende Formulierung macht es vielleicht klarer:

> Es ging offenbar darum, wie er mit fünfzehn **einmal** vor dem
>   Klassenfiesling eingeknickt war oder so was.

---

<sub>English: ... once at age of 15 ...</sub>

Comment: Noch deutlicher: "... mit fünfzehn Jahren einmal vor dem ..."

Answer (score 6):

> Es ging offenbar darum, wie er mit fünfzehn **mal** vor dem Klassenfiesling eingeknickt war oder so was.

*Apparently, it was about him backing off from the class bully at age fifteen **once** or something like that.*

The verb **einknicken** does not literally mean *to bow*, but metaphorically. The whole idea of this sentence is the narrator thinks that situation was unimportant, but the person he talks about has a completely different opinion. That's why we have *mal* and *oder so was* in here.

Comment: *mal* is a short form of *einmal* here. At least in Austria, it refers to no certain time and has nothing to do with once or twice...

Answer (score 3):

Or, much more pragmatic:

The point apparently / obviously was that at age 15, he had (once) caved in to the creep of his class, or something like that.

Cheers!

Comment: Bitte versuche, alle deine Beiträge nur von einem Konto zu verfassen. Mit einer Registrierung kannst du mit der Zeit Reputationspunkte sammeln und bekommst Zugriff auf weitere Funktionen (siehe [help] "privileges"). Mit einer Registrierung kannst du  auch deine Konten zusammenführen lassen (siehe https://german.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)